# Walking Tour for the first time app user

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am implementing walking tour for the first time user in the application. I do not know is there a better way of doing it, but I have implemented the following approach which detects user taps via tap gesture recognition.

I wonder how could I handle if I have more than one image? Or is there any better or recommended approach for the walking tour?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];

     UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
     recognizer.delegate = self;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled =  YES;
    self.imageView = imageView;
}

- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognize
{
     [self.imageView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PageViewController will be another good option for this. You can try this control.

[PageViewController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pageviewcontroller)

Answer (score 1):

It is totally up to you how you want yo implement this. The approach you have mentioned have nothing wrong.

For your question if you have more than one images then you can create a container `view` on which you can add multiple `imageViews`. And On Touch on that container you can show hide image view based on your sequence.